# I have installed Sqoop(1.4.7) in my system and while running import i am getting classnotdefexception

Tags: sqoop

I have installed Sqoop(1.4.7) in my system and while running import command I am getting `Classnotdef exception` please find below import command and exception detail. please help me out.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool.validateHiveOptions(BaseSqoopTool.java:1583)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.validateOptions(ImportTool.java:1178)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:137)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoad
```

Command ---

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/emp --table employee --username root --password Root123# --target-dir /data/sqoop -m 1
```

Comment: Check whether a **sqljdbc42.jar** file exists in the Sqoop lib directory or not.